# Create a Swift HTTP mock with alternate data

Tags: swift, xctest

I have a mocked HTTPManager, and I want it to either return a userIDResonse or a tokenResponse.

To be able to do this I made the mock conform to a protocol to allow this to be set within the test.

```
let userIDResponse = """
{\"user_id\":\"5a7ab957a225856b38f49bb4\"}
"""

let tokenResponse = """
{\"access_token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjczMUE3OUEyMjY3QjY4Q0EwNTc5QjYzRjdFMkY0QjlBQkZFMENEMTUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJjeHA1b2laN2FNb0ZlYllfZmk5TG1yX2d6UlUifQ.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.q4-SF5KBVSwN4bFhcQ88icR9X2jzz_JH2K4EpDgS-oZjjppNruckxfTjauVqcwG8zPR0eGzx5CBXiAfMeg9akShWajqBZ9rkCsqjXw6Ef74J9cTBDhxTEUL0v7P0zm_fVNOutM_UJQ-DiQr2gAO0mfAxMhOiQ_uXlKoM2RYGKjfMkH6Ym7kBjtRAhho8pPVmtQiBmVFI5OUVXNU3rPVgB7sx-I1LZmUZBZoy7T4s14TAuE4yiUyTBgO5joyRsZtMdFybna8CRK_ylS3WC6wOBNm74O9IrZlbsiradtLzMG-9E8AnjbvH4RYR68H2xpt562PfnGD_VC9NXFQ7iRrRMw\"}
"""
```

Used by the Mock

```
protocol HTTPManagerMockProtocol {
    func setResponse(response: String.UTF8View)
}

typealias HTTPMock = HTTPManagerProtocol & HTTPManagerMockProtocol

class HTTPManagerMock: HTTPMock {

    var data = Data(userIDResponse.utf8)

    func setResponse(response: String.UTF8View) {
        data = Data(response)
    }

    func get(urlString: String, parameters: [String : String], completionBlock: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        completionBlock(.success(data))
    }

}
```

So then in my test I have to set the reponse:

```
let httpMock = HTTPManagerMock()
httpMock.setResponse(response: tokenResponse.utf8)
sut = Login(serverString: "serverURL", headers: [:], httpManager: httpMock )
```

In some ways this seems ok, however it means I cannot use the setup function in my tests which results in repeated code within my test classes.

Which approach can mean I can have a mock with different output without generating extra test code?

Answer (score 0):

Make a parameterized helper method to create your System Under Test.

```
private func makeLogin(response: String) -> Login {
    let httpMock = HTTPManagerMock()
    httpMock.setResponse(response: response.utf8)
    return Login(serverString: "serverURL", headers: [:], httpManager: httpMock)
}
```

That way, you can vary the response across different tests. And if you have tests where you don't really care about the response and want to provide dummy data, that can be a default value in the helper.